# How access Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 7(guest user) through external network?

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to access my Ubuntu 18.04 home desktop from a Windows 7 machine at my college which I have no admin privileges.

I want to be able to see the GUI and not just a terminal interface.

Google search shows me a lot of results, but I didn't found an example showing step-by-step.

I believe I should install a VNC software and after that configure a public IP or DNS, this last part seems to be difficult.

Comment: Yes vnc for desktop sharing, about network access, you need to give more information. Are the two computers on the same internal network? If no, if the connection should go via the Internet, security measures must be taken

Comment: Internet connection. I found many tutorials talking about this, but in the comment section someone always would write a huge text saying how dangerous the setup was, I hope to find a configuration that provides some minimum degree of safety.

Comment: Solution : `Ubuntu vnc server` -- ssh tunnel -- `Windows putty` & `Windows vnc client`

Comment: VNC over ssh tunnel is a common practice so you will easily find docs about it. windows putty will be the Windows side of tunnel client